# How to set C++ standard in Bazel project or workspace?

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm currently migrating a multipackage C++14 project to Bazel, but whenever I run `$ bazel build` on linux I end up getting build errors because Bazel is calling the compiler with `-std=c++0x`.

One of the requirements for this project is to gradually migrate its packages to C++17 once the build system is up and running.   However, after browsing through Bazel's docs I saw no reference to how to set a project's target C++ standard version.  CMake handles this trivially and effortlessly through its `CXX_STANDARD` target property, but so far I saw no reference to this usecase being supported by Bazel.

With this in mind, does anyone know if Bazel allows users to specify C++ standard versions for specific projects/workspaces?  If it does, is it possible to provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1):

The [envoy](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/a43d8fb6c2f674180e7d42dc105dc86ff971e527/.bazelrc#L23) project is good place to start when you need to learn how to tune your C/C++ toolchain. In your case just add that line to the `.bazelrc` file:

```
build:linux --cxxopt=-std=c++14
```

Answer (score 0):

Other good way to add custom compiler flags is to wrap cc_{binary,library} into your own macro:

```py
def my_cc_library(
  name,
  copts=[],
  **kwargs):
  cc_library(
    name = name,
    copts = copts + ["-std=c++14"],
    **kwargs)
```